# How to run stored procedure in Azure Data Factory DataFlow SQL Server source

Tags: azure-data-factory

When using an Azure SQL Server source, I use the Query option and specify a stored procedure to run.  When I paste in the same code in Management Studio, it works, but when executed from ADF source using `Query` option, it errors with the following condition.  How can I call a stored procedure using Query option?

```
{"message":"at Source 'Source': com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'EXECUTE'.. Details:at Source 'Source': com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'EXECUTE'.","failureType":"UserError","target":"SyncData","errorCode":"DFExecutorUserError"}
```

Here is the query I'm passing that works when called from SSMS:

```
EXECUTE [dbo].[sp_ReplicaGetChanges] @ReplicaVersion = 0, @FirstTimeFlag = 1, @SourceSchema = 'dbo', @SourceTable = 'Brand', @UpdateColumns = NULL
```

[image]

Comment: I tried it on my side and get the same error. I think it may not supported.

Comment: But something is strange, we could run `EXECUTE...` statement  in Copy Active Source query operation, but can not in Data Flow Source query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UDFs are supported in Data Flows, but not SPs

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-azure-sql-database#source-transformation

Comment: Thanks @Mark.  Do you happen to know the rational behind not supporting that stored procedure?  Can we expect to see that support in the future?  Seems reasonable since CopyActivity and LookupActivity both support procedures.

Comment: It is a very reasonable ask. Would you be kind enough to submit your suggestion on User Voice so that we can gauge proper priority to enable the feature? TY! https://feedback.azure.com/forums/270578-data-factory

Comment: BTW  Mark - Thanks for always taking the time to answer most of my ADF questions.  It's a pretty cool platform and having your response to questions is awesome.

Answer (score 0):

Some analytics system does not like execute and dbo.
Try to change execute to exec and/or remove dbo. From sp
E.g.   Exec sp_ReplicaGetChanges

Answer (score 0):

For the record I will share my experience just in case someone finds it useful.

TLDR: just **type in** the schema name and the stored procedure.

Nowadays, in DataFlow sources, one can select "Stored procedure" as a source option (rather than table or query). I was searching how to do it because it was not detecting the stored procedures by default (showing blank dropdowns). Because the dataset is defined at table level, I was afraid it would not work. However, the solution was as simple as typing-in the schema and the procedure names (one gets used to have every option available in dropdowns in ADF). After that, I was able to import the variables used by the procedure as shown in the image
[image: dataflow source, source options tab]